# 16:9 Aspect Ratio App & Background (Accounting for space taken by the Nav)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Ok, I am working on creating a simple game for IOS / Android and I'm having a little trouble with consistency in the layout across devices.

My new hypothesis is essentially if I develop the layout in 16:9 ratio, it will scale well for most / all devices.  I have achieved maintaining the ratio on the outside wrapper of the game, but the game area is also a 16:9 ratio background *image*, which I cannot get to properly scale down to fill the "game area"

For this, let's assume there is 30px on top and 30px on bottom of the page for navigation, which means the "game area" has a height of 100% - 60px and width of 100%, which leads to the problem.  despite the background image being 16:9 ratio, that area is no longer a 16:9 canvas area.

My attempts:

1. Change the image to lop off 60px -> this failed horribly
2. Centering the background image on the "game area", which isn't too bad, but we lose a lot of space on the sides. [Background 100% of inner DIV](https://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/fukhjn53/)
3. Using canvas to force the image into the area, but things get blurry: [Background Using Canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/xoehf6kp/)
4. Moving the background image to the outside wrapper / body.  This actually looks quite good! BUT I lose 60px of the image still that is covered by the NAV. Seen Here: [Background 100% of wrapper that is 16:9](https://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/vtxjsbnf/)

Any other thoughts on how to get a better result?

This is the current code:

```css
#Game_Wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vw * 9 / 16);
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightblue url('https://i.imgur.com/tRFltCI.png') 0 0/contain no-repeat;
}
#Game_Area {
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
#GUI_Top {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 30px;
 background: grey;
}
#GUI_Top p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#GUI_Bottom {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 30px;
 background: grey;
}
#GUI_Bottom p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
/* 100 * 16/9 = 177.778 */
@media (min-width: 177.778vh) {
    #Game_Wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        width: calc(100vh * 16 / 9);
    }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>
 <div id="Game_Wrapper">
  <!-- This will hold the entire game and GUI -->
  <div id="GUI_Top">
   <!-- This is where the top GUI will be -->
            <p>This is the top GUI / NAV</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Game_Area">
   <!-- This is where you can interact with the actual game -->
  </div>
  <div id="GUI_Bottom">
   <!-- This is where the bottom GUI will be -->
   <p>This is the bottom GUI / NAV</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: On your example `Background 100% of inner DIV`, did you try `background-size` attribute is `cover` instead of `contain`?

Comment: Yeah, so the cover on background-size cuts the image off though and I need the whole thing to be viewable, which is what led me to try forcing it into a canvas despite the size.

Answer (score 0):

As you already notice, it's impossible to keep the 16:9 ratio of the image inside a container that is also 16:9 and having other elements.

What I advise is to fill the remaining space with an extension of the image so we may think it's the same image.

Here is an approximation of how it shoud look. I simply filled the empty space with the same image but blurred. The idea is to find the good pattern to make it visually better:

```css
#Game_Wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 9 / 16);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#Game_Area {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/tRFltCI.png') center/contain no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#Game_Area:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  bottom:-10px;
  z-index:-1;
  background:  
    url('https://i.imgur.com/tRFltCI.png') right/contain no-repeat,
    url('https://i.imgur.com/tRFltCI.png') left/contain no-repeat;
 filter:blur(8px);
}


#GUI_Top {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: grey;
}

#GUI_Top p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#GUI_Bottom {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: grey;
}

#GUI_Bottom p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/* 100 * 16/9 = 177.778 */

@media (min-width: 177.778vh) {
  #Game_Wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vh * 16 / 9);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body>
  <div id="Game_Wrapper">
    <!-- This will hold the entire game and GUI -->
    <div id="GUI_Top">
      <!-- This is where the top GUI will be -->
      <p>This is the top GUI / NAV</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Game_Area">
      <!-- This is where you can interact with the actual game -->
    </div>
    <div id="GUI_Bottom">
      <!-- This is where the bottom GUI will be -->
      <p>This is the bottom GUI / NAV</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```